# Image Processing

Tags: raspbian, opencv

I implemented face recognition algorithm in raspberry pi(python 2.7 is was used), i have many sets of faces, if the captured face is one in database then the face is detected(i am using eigen faces algo). My question is can i know whose face(persons name) is detected? (can we have sort of tags to image and display name corresponding to it when the face is detected)
Note: OpenCV used

Comment: Are your faces labeled?

Comment: just the faces have file name....can i use the file name to assign a name to it..but then in positive faces databases we have many faces how to distinguish and how to know which face is recognized.